# Segue not passing values

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm creating a segue while trying to pass information of a contact (loggedinUser) to the destinationViewControllers's contact (currentUser), but it's not going through for some reason. Is something wrong with the code below?

Original view:

```
...
self.loggedInUser.firstName = @"first name";
self.loggedInUser.lastName = @"last name";
self.loggedInUser.company = @"company"
self.loggedInUser.position = @"position";
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"profileSegue" sender:self];
...

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
ProfileViewController *pvc = (ProfileViewController *) [segue destinationViewController];
pvc.currentUser = self.loggedInUser; }
```

Then I'm displaying the values in labels in
DestinationViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSString *fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", currentUser.firstName, currentUser.lastName];
    fullNameLabel.text = fullName;
    companyLabel.text = currentUser.company;
    positionLabel.text = currentUser.position;
}
```

Both loggedInUser and currentUser are of type "Contact". But the labels just end up displaying null. Am I missing something obvious?

*EDIT*

It's a problem with self.loggedinUser not being passed through to prepareForSegue.

Header Code:

```
#import "Contact.h"

@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController
{
}

...

@property (nonatomic, retain) Contact *loggedInUser;
```

Comment: you sure when `prepareForSegue:` method called self.loggedInUser has the values? check it once more. i suggest you to add method in `ProfileViewController` class which takes `Contact` class parameter which is obviously self.loggedInUser then set all values there.

Comment: yes Rahul, this was the problem! It doesn't have the values for some reason. still debugging.

Comment: what u get when u do NSLog(@"%@", self. loggedInUser); in prepareForSegue?

Comment: i get a (null) value.

Comment: can you show code after `performSegueWithIdentifier:` ? one more think r u forgetting to allocate your self.loggedInUser object? (just for curiosity :p)

Comment: did u write -(BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender{return NO;}

Comment: Put code where you have init your self.loggedInUser?

Comment: OHH SHIT I haven't instantiated it ><

Comment: It seem like you have not allocate and init your self. loggedInUser. Do you write something like self.loggedInUser = [[<userclass> alloc] init]; ?

Comment: self.loggedInUser = [[Contact alloc] init];

Comment: oops yes i just deleted that comment

Comment: -[Contact setFirstName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x856bef0'

Comment: For that I have to see your contact.h and contact.m

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35966/discussion-between-crdave-and-allen)

Answer (score 1):

I assume `viewDidLoad` was called before `prepareFortSegue`, i.e. when `currentUser` still is `nil`. I suggest moving your code from `viewDidLoad` to `viewWillAppear`. Or you could set breakpoints to check the order of calls.

Comment: I actually successfully passed a string value, so I know the order is correct now. But there's a problem with passing objects...which I'm still trying to figure out.

Comment: I found the error! For some reason, the self.loggedinUser is out of scope when in the "prepareForSegue" method. I've included it in the header files, so I'm still trying to figure out why this is the case.